# A property in Child Object in Parent Object-A is changed when a new property in Child Object in Parent Object-B is added

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, object, oop

Consider this object

```
{
    "ClassId": 101,
    "Sections": [
        {
            "SectionId": 201,
            "Subjects": [
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10101,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2101
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2102
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10102,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2103
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2104
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SectionId": 202,
            "Subjects": [
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10101,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2105
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2106
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10102,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2107
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2108
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above example I mentioned, the subjectIds in both sections are same.
As SubjectIds in both sections are matching, when ever I am trying to update activities on base of section Id all the activities in Subject which are matching with the subject Id are getting changed.

Let's say in above example:
In SectionId 201, for subjectId 10101, I have added a new array of Activities with ActivityId as 2101, 2102.
After this, in sectionId 202, for subjectId 10101, I have added a new array of activities with ActivityId as 2105, 2106.
Now the activities in SubjectId 10101 of SectionId 201 is changed to ActivityId as 2105, 2106.

I dont know understand why is this happening. I dont want the first set's values to be changed.

I tried this

```
for (var i = 0; i < classes.Count; i++)
{
    var cls = classes[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < cls.Sections.Count; j++)
    {
        var sec = cls.Sections[j];
        for (var k = 0; k < sec.Subjects.Count; k++)
        {
            var sub = sec.Subjects[k];
            for (var l = 0; l < sub.Activities.Count; l++)
            {
               sub.Activities = sectionSubjectActivities
                        .Where(act => act.ClassId == cls.ClassId && act.SectionId == sec.SectionId && act.SubjectId == sub.SubjectId)
                        .Select(activity => new ActivityDTO
                        {
                            ActivityId = activity.Id
                        }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to get this,

```
{
    "ClassId": 101,
    "Sections": [
        {
            "SectionId": 201,
            "Subjects": [
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10101,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2101
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2102
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10102,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2103
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2104
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SectionId": 202,
            "Subjects": [
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10101,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2105
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2106
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10102,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2107
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2108
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but I am getting this

```
{
    "ClassId": 101,
    "Sections": [
        {
            "SectionId": 201,
            "Subjects": [
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10101,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2101
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2102
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10102,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2103
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2104
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SectionId": 202,
            "Subjects": [
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10101,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2101
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2102
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SubjectId": 10102,
                    "Activities": [
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2103
                        },
                        {
                            "ActivityId": 2104
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For Section 201, Subject 10101; I added 2101, 2102

For Section 202, Subject 10101; I added 2105, 2106

Now for Section 201, Subject 10101, 2101, 2102 are replaced with 2105, 2106

Answer (score 0):

its not clear what do you want, there is an example to add or replace Activity
I hope it gives you clear view on where and what happening

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"ClassId\":101,\"Sections\":[{\"SectionId\":201,\"Subjects\":[{\"SubjectId\":10101,\"Activities\":[{\"ActivityId\":2101},{\"ActivityId\":2102}]},{\"SubjectId\":10102,\"Activities\":[{\"ActivityId\":2103},{\"ActivityId\":2104}]}]},{\"SectionId\":202,\"Subjects\":[{\"SubjectId\":10101,\"Activities\":[{\"ActivityId\":2105},{\"ActivityId\":2106}]},{\"SubjectId\":10102,\"Activities\":[{\"ActivityId\":2107},{\"ActivityId\":2108}]}]}]}";
    
    var cls = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(json);
    cls.Dump();

    //add
    cls.Sections.Where(w => w.SectionId == 202)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Subjects.Where(s=> s.SubjectId == 10101)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Activities.Add(new Activity() {ActivityId= 77777})
    ;
    //replace
    cls.Sections.Where(w => w.SectionId == 202)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Subjects.Where(s => s.SubjectId == 10102)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Activities = new List<Activity>(){
            new Activity(){ActivityId = 11111},
            new Activity(){ActivityId = 22222}
        }
    ;


    cls.Dump();






}

public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

there are 2 code blocks (i am using Newtonsoft lib)

```
//add
    cls.Sections.Where(w => w.SectionId == 202)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Subjects.Where(s=> s.SubjectId == 10101)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Activities.Add(new Activity() {ActivityId= 77777})
    ;
```

[image]

and to replace:

```
//replace
    cls.Sections.Where(w => w.SectionId == 202)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Subjects.Where(s => s.SubjectId == 10102)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Activities = new List<Activity>(){
            new Activity(){ActivityId = 11111},
            new Activity(){ActivityId = 22222}
        };
```

as you see, second call on updated object, so it included added Activity.

[image]